# How do window functions and the group by clause interact?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, window-functions

I do understand [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-window.html) and [group by](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-select.html) separately.

But what happens when you use both a window function and a group by clause in the same query ?

- Are the selected rows grouped first, then considered by the window function ?
- Or does the window function executes first, then the resulting values are grouped by `group by` ?
- Something else ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WINDOW):

> If the query contains any window functions, these functions are evaluated **after any grouping, aggregation, and HAVING filtering is performed**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>