# How do group by and window functions interact in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293435/how-do-window-functions-and-the-group-by-clause-interact), I learned that window functions are evaluated after the group by function in PostgresSQL.

I'd like to know what happens when you use a group by and window function in the same query in Spark. I have the same questions as the poster from the previous question:

- Are the selected rows grouped first, then considered by the window function ?
- Or does the window function execute first, then the resulting values are grouped by the group by?
- Something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you have **window** and **group by** in same query then

- Group by performed **`first`** then **`window`** function will be applied on the groupby dataset.
- You can check query explain plan for more details.

**`Example:`**

```
//sample data
spark.sql("select * from tmp").show()
//+-------+----+
//|trip_id|name|
//+-------+----+
//|      1|   a|
//|      2|   b|
//+-------+----+


spark.sql("select row_number() over(order by trip_id),trip_id,count(*) cnt from tmp group by trip_id").explain()
//== Physical Plan ==
//*(4) Project [row_number() OVER (ORDER BY trip_id ASC NULLS FIRST ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)#150, trip_id#10, cnt#140L]
//+- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(trip_id#10 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS row_number() OVER (ORDER BY //trip_id ASC NULLS FIRST ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)#150], [trip_id#10 ASC NULLS FIRST]
//   +- *(3) Sort [trip_id#10 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
//      +- Exchange SinglePartition
//         +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[trip_id#10], functions=[count(1)])
//            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(trip_id#10, 200)
//               +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[trip_id#10], functions=[partial_count(1)])
//                  +- LocalTableScan [trip_id#10]
```

---

**`*(2) groupby executed first`**

**`*(4) window function applied on the result of grouped dataset.`**

In case if you have window clause **`subquery`** and outer query have group by then subquery(window) executed first then outer query(groupBy) executed next.

**`Ex:`**
`spark.sql("select trip_id,count(*) from(select *,row_number() over(order by trip_id)rn from tmp)e group by trip_id ").explain()`